# Wordpress - HTML Entities are being Displayed

Tags: wordpress, xhtml, character-encoding

I am currently developing a Wordpress site, and everytime a comment, page or article is added/retrieved, the HTML entites in the text are encoded, particulary single quotes/double quotes, like #089A.

Is there a setting or something that can be enabled/disabled that does this? I've tried the usual Google searches but alas I can't find anything.

Cheers,

MiG

Comment: Character entities start with `&` and end in `;`.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I forgot what it was off the top of my head :)

Comment: Do you mean the entities are visible in the browser, but not the symbols they represent? Or do you want to prevent replacing (double) quotes by their entities? I think the latter can be done by [disabling the `wptexturize` filter](http://www.jasonlitka.com/2007/09/25/wordpress-plugin-disable-wptexturize/).

Comment: Yes the entities are visible, but not the symbols they represent such as "'". I think double quotes are being problematic too. I'll have a look at the wptexturize filter. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update this. I've been looking at the site today and it seems that the offending HTML entitiy is "&#8211"

The posts are being returned via AJAX in a JSON response and instead of seeing – I see "&#8211" plus the semi-colon.

Any reason for this?

Cheers,

MiG

Comment: Turns out it was my fault using text() instead of html(). oops! :)